# Variantes, elisão e crase da vogal temática

Tags: verbos, crase, morfema

Eu estava a ler Valter Kehdi e as seguintes citações são a explicação dada pelo autor para as variantes da vogal temática nos verbos da 1ª e 2ª conjugação. (Vou começar por incluir a estrutura desinêncial do verbo, depois a explicação do autor e por fim as tabelas com exemplos das variantes):

> Assim, temos uma fórmula geral da estrutura do vocâbulo verbal português:
>
> **T (R + VT) + SF (SMT + SNP)**

As siglas acima siginificam:

- T. Tema
- R. Radical
- VT. Vogal temática
- SF. Sintagma flexional (ou desinência)
- SMT. Sintagma modo-tempo
- SNP. Sintagma número-pessoa

> A vogal temática da primeira conjugação apresenta as variantes *-e-* e *-o-*, respectivamente (na primeira e na terceira pessoas do singular do pretérito perfeito do indicativo: amei, amou); a única variante da vogal temática da segunda conjugação é *-i-*, que ocorre no pretérito imperfeito do indicativo, na primeira pessoa do singular do pretérito perfeito do indicativo e no particípio passado (vendia, vendi, vendido).
>
> (...)
>
> É falso interpretar a ausência de vogal temática numa forma verbal como um caso de alomorfe Ø. Em formas como *amo* e *ame*, p.ex., não figura a vogal temática em virtude da regra fonológica da elisão: é uma vogal átona que cai em contacto com a vogal da desinência:
>
> > *ama* + *o* = *amo*; *ama* + *e* = *ame*
>
> No caso de *vendia*, deu-se a crase do alomorfe *-i-* (da vogal temática) com a vogal inicial da desinência *-ia*:
>
> > *vend* + *i* + *ia* = *vendia*
>
> Valter Kehdi in "Morfemas do Português".

**Variantes da vogal temática na 1ª conjugação:**

(As variantes estão assinaladas com negrito e as flexões sem variante estão incluídas para comparação.)

| Pessoa | Base Verbal | Vogal Temática | Modo-Tempo | Número-Pessoa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Pretérito Perfeito do Indicativo** |  |  |  |  |
| Eu | cant | **e** | Ø | i |
| Tu | cant | a | Ø | ste |
| Ele | cant | **o** | Ø | u |
| Nós | cant | á | Ø | mos |
| Vós | cant | a | Ø | stes |
| Eles | cant | a | ra | m |

**Variantes da vogal temática na 2ª conjugação:**

| Pessoa | Base Verbal | Vogal Temática | Modo-Tempo | Número-Pessoa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Pretérito Imperfeito do Indicativo** |  |  |  |  |
| Eu | vend | Ø | ia | o |
| Tu | vend | Ø | ia | s |
| Ele | vend | Ø | ia | Ø |
| Nós | vend | Ø | ía | mos |
| Vós | vend | Ø | íe | is |
| Eles | vend | Ø | ia | m |
| **Pretérito Perfeito do Indicativo** |  |  |  |  |
| Eu | vend | Ø | Ø | i |
| **Particípio Passado** |  |  |  |  |
|  | vend | i | do | Ø |

**Variantes da vogal temática na 3ª conjugação:**

| Pessoa | Base Verbal | Vogal Temática | Modo-Tempo | Número-Pessoa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Presente do Indicativo** |  |  |  |  |
| Eu | part | Ø | Ø | o |
| Tu | part | e | Ø | s |
| Ele | part | e | Ø | Ø |
| Nós | part | i | Ø | mos |
| Vós | part | Ø | Ø | is |
| Eles | part | e | Ø | m |

A minha pergunta é se há um método geral para pensar sobre a vogal temática? Por exemplo, como se explica as variantes da vogal temática no presente do indicativo da 3ª conjugação (Valter Kehdi não explica o caso da 3ª conjugação)?

Sendo um verbo da 3ª conjugação a vogal temática deve ser *-i-* ou *-í-* então como se explica aparecer o *-e-* e o caso da 2ª pessoa do plural em que não aparece vogal temática?

Voltando a olhar para o exemplo dado por Kehdi (verbo da 2ª conjugação):

> No caso de *vendia*, deu-se a crase do alomorfe *-i-* (da vogal temática) com a vogal inicial da desinência *-ia*:
>
> *vend* + *i* + *ia* = *vendia*

Não compreendo se isto significa que devemos olhar para ausências da vogal temática (em todas as flexões do paradigma) sempre como um caso que deve ser resolvido por elisão ou crase? Mas mais ainda, quando Kehdi diz para o exemplo do pretérito imperfeito da 2ª conjugação (que resulta em *vendia*) antes, segunda o autor, de ser dar a crase ela aplica-se não à vogal temática *-er-* dos verbos da 2ª conjugação mas a uma alomorfe desta *-i-*... (Para complicar um pouco mais a vogal temática é absorvida pela desinência modo-tempo - portanto nem sei bem sé é uma "variante" como lhe chama o autor ou só uma ausência por crase...) Não devia ser:

> *vend* + *e* + *ia*

em vez de (como diz Kehdi):

> *vend* + *i* + *ia*

e uma elisão por a vogal temática ser *-e-* em vez de *-i-*?

O mesmo para o exemplo da 3ª conjugação consideramos a 2ª pessoa do singular e 3ª pessoa do singular e plural variante da vogal temática? Cunha&Cintra também não explicam isto na *"Nova gramática do português contemporâneo"* é difícil encontrar uma explicação completa nas gramáticas.

Comment: Tou com a cabeça a andar à roda!

Comment: @Jacinto ainda não fui capaz de encontrar um texto recente que tenha um explicação mais completa e detalhada que seja considerada consensual (Kehdi tem muito mérito por ter abordado o problema quando e como o fez).

Comment: @Jacinto encontrei isto desenvolvido numa publicação mais recente a [Gramática da Língua Portuguesa, de Maria Mateus, et all](https://webs.ucm.es/info/circulo/no17/mateus.htm) no capítulo 22. Quando tiver tempo vou tentar revisitar o assunto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há um fator muito importante quando se quer explicar uma irregularidade em qualquer paradigma das línguas: o fator **etimológico**!

Em latim a conjugação da terceira pessoa do singular no presente do indicativo do verbo que deu origem a "partir", por exemplo, é "*partis*". Sendo a última vogal um i-curto, sabemos que era pronunciada mais ou menos como [ɪ], e este i-curto tranformou-se em [e] no português, assim é de se esperar que "*partis*" se tranforme em "partes" (mesmo assim, acrescento que sempre se notou uma tendência de neutralização de i~e pós-tônicos, como no português brasileiro atual).

Quanto a "vendia", desconfio que a razão também seja puramente etimológica da seguinte forma:

> uēndēbat > uendeba > uende(i)a > uendeia > *junção de "e" + "i"* uendia > vendia

Comment: Entretanto para além da explicação que encontrei no livro que indiquei nos comentários acima, encontrei outra ainda mais detalhada em *"Fonética, Fonologia e Morfologia do Português", Universiade Aberta, 1990.* Não auto-respondi à pergunta entretanto por falta de tempo, e também por a resposta completa ser complexa e eu não entrever outra solução senão citar parte substancial do texto.

Comment: @bad_coder Não deixe de postar sua resposta quando puder!

Comment: @stafusa não desisti de postar, entretanto também estive concentrado em atingir os níveis de 10k no SO e de 25k no MSE, só me falta meia-duzia de respostas para completar esses patamares... Depois terei mais tempo para voltar a concentrar-me no pt.se :)

Comment: @bad_coder Legal! E qual vai ser seu objetivo aqui, 5k, 10k,..? :-)

Comment: @stafusa o objectivo aqui é qualidade (e os 2k claro, para ter os mod tools) quero focar-me mais na fonética nos tempos vindouros portanto o objectivo é aprender a matéria e contribuir bons posts que sejam úteis à comunidade.

Comment: @bad_coder Que você foca na qualidade é evidente. Focar na fonética também é ótimo, não tem tanta gente que pode responder bem nesse tema. Agora 2k... c'mon, isso você essencialmente já tem.